# Override an abstract class of a base class with template

Tags: c#, templates, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class

I have a Base class with a template. Within this class there is an abstract method with a return type of the type in the template (see below).

I wish to create a new class , Derived , which inherits from this Base class , which (as expected) must "override" that method.

My question is how do I declare and implement the Derived class and the "overridden" method ?

Thanks allot in advance,

Guy.

```
public abstract class Base<MyType> 
{
    protected abstract MyType Foo();
}


public class Derived : Base ????? 
{
    protected override MyType Foo() ?????
    {
         return new MyType();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply specify the actual type for the generic base class, i.e something like:

```
public class Derived : Base<MyType>
{
    protected override MyType Foo()
    {
        // some implementation that returns an instance of type MyType
    }
}
```

Where `MyType` is the actual type you want to specify.

The other option would be to keep the derived class as generic, so something like:

```
public class Derived<T> : Base<T>
{
    protected override T Foo()
    {
        // some implementation that returns an instance of type T
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must specify concrete type for `Base` or make `Derived` also generic:

```
public class Derived : Base<int> 
{
    protected override int Foo();
    {
         return 0;
    }   
}
```

or generic version:

```
public class Derived<TMyType> : Base<TMyType> 
{
    protected override TMyType Foo();
    {
         return default(TMyType);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare it in the same way:

```
public class Derived<MyType> : Base<MyType>
{
    protected override MyType Foo()
    {
         return new MyType();
    }   
}
```

Comment: You'd need a generic constraint to ensure there is a parameterless constructor for that specific code to work, of course...